# VSE How to render faster?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I did go ahead and do my part to look it up
There are answers out there but they are years old and outdated when compared to the current version/build

Currently, I'm rendering a video that's about 20 mins long and it says that the estimate is over 2.5 hrs

My 1st question is if that's normal
And my 2nd, how to optimize rendering

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I already did System Pref>Cycles>CUDA

Comment: It is normal, not much has changed. The VSE is a very old tool, with very little development and has yet to catch up with the current formats and ways to edit video. For anything longer than a few seconds use a proper Video Editing app. At this point in time most dedicated apps are so much more efficient than blender. Spare yourself the pain and use your time to be creative, and not rendering.

Comment: I think it has gotten some updates   

I also think it takes about the same time in other apps, I saw a lot of this being said by others while I looked for an answer    

That it's mostly dependent on your setup/hardware
Dang not being able to space my sentences out is killing me lol

Comment: It's gotten updates for sure, the whole interface changed when it came to a certain version (cant remember)  
I know this bcuz I was working on a video and when I updated, the video's edits were all out of place

Comment: Previously, I used the [blender render controller](https://github.com/Isti115/BlenderRenderController) which uses multithreading with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Parallel Render add-on will allow you to render, from the Blender Render panel, using all cores, which will give you a speed-up: https://github.com/elmopl/ktba/blob/master/scripts/addons/parallel_render.py

Another thing which may speed up export is to change the colorspace from Filmic to Standard.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know what kind of cuts in time we're talking about with this addon?  
I also don't really use addons but I guess I should start to since it seems that's what blender runs on  

And I don't really know anything about those colorspace settings 

Comment: If you are editing video **the color management should not be set to filmic**. It is not about speed:  you will get the colors all wrong. Filmic only works on scene referred scenes or with sources encoded in Log (again, to be de-loged into scene referred values). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-gets-greyish-touch

Comment: To answer the question regarding performance: I have 12 cores, and this pretty much sped up redering by a factor > 10. I could also see all cores being at 100%, except the last 30 seconds. So you can easily calculate your performance gain by counting the cores of your processor.