# The color of my video is wrong when I input it into "Composition"

Tags: node-editor, tracking, color

So, I'm tracking a video, then applying a vide on top using "Motion Tracking" and "Compositing" in Blender. My video's colors always came out a bit "whiter" and "higher contrast" than the original, so I fiddled around with the color values and found out that setting the source video's settings to "Raw" (In "Footage Settings" -> "Color Space") fixed it!

However, now, when I try the same thing, it won't work anymore.
In the "Tracking" panel, changing the settings to "Raw" fixes the colors, but if I go into "Compositing" and do the input color (in the "image" node) to "Raw", the video turns much whiter and brighter than it should be. (Changing it to sRGB turns it darker, but still too white compared to the original footage.)

I currently have this node setup (see below), but the video footage is the same color even if I connect the "Image" node to "Composite" and "Viewer" directly.

[image: pic1]

And THIS is how the image looks in the "Tracking" panel, and how it originally looks:

[image: pic2]

How can I fix this? What causes the video to get whiter than it should be?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender image output gets greyish touch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-gets-greyish-touch)

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Raw as the color space for video.

The issue is that by default blender is set to use Filmic as the color space. It is meant to render images using a wide dynamic range, not for dealing with video.

Your video is in a Rec709 or sRGB color space, so it should be displayed in sRGB color space.

**Images viewed or processed in the wrong color space will always look wrong**.

In the color management section, set the display to sRGB and the view transform  to standard (which is the dumbed down name the developers set for sRGB).

[image]

And set your footage to use sRGB.

Comment: Thanks so much! I think that fixed it. What format do you recommend that I export it in? AVI JPEG, or AVI RAW?

Comment: no unrelated questions in the comments please. for new questions use a new post.

Comment: As much as I love the professional answers in here, I sometimes dislike how everyone believes that they MUST keep the rules, even when it's much easier or even more effective to go around it once in a while. It is much more ineffective and time consuming to write an entire post describing the problem, when the context already exists in this post. Could you please answer my question so I can mark the post as solved, without me needing to clutter up the site with very short, context-less questions?