# Movie clip editor messes up with my colors

Tags: video

Before I state my question, you need to know that I'm way out of my league. I'm just trying to stabilize some timelapse and that's all I'm using Blender for.

I have a few hundred PNG files that I took with a camera and then adjusted their colors using Darktable. Now, I'm trying to track and then stabilize them before turning them into a clip. I managed to learn how to do so after watching some online videos and everything worked perfectly. It's just that the rendered images and also the viewport within Blender change the color of my images. I mean when I open the same files in Darktable or even in gThumb, the colors look perfect. But when I drag and drop them into Blender, everything is different. Here's a sample shot:

[image]

On the left, you can see Blender's viewport (the output render file is the same) and on the right is the same file opened in gThumb (Darktable shows it like this as well). Can someone please help me find what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting this so I can post the pic. I can't be 100% certain this will solve your problem, but you likely find some success playing around with the color management settings. See below:

[image: ColorManagement]

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: To be more precise, if the image is using sRGB there is no reason to use filmic blender, the view transform should be "standard". https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWh4A.png Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-gets-greyish-touch/176760#176760