# How to imitate LAMBERT diffuse shading and COOKTOR specular shading in 2.8?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

I'm new to blender and was working on updating some code for a project from 2.79 and 2.8. But it appears that the LAMBERT shading and COOKTORR shading isn't supported anymore because Blender doesn't use the internal rendering engine anymore. I was wondering if there's any way to replicate the effect this has in 2.8 using Eevee? I used to get a white background and the renders had some sort of depth to them but it seems flatter and the background is grey for some reason.

```
def makeMaterial(name, diffuse, specular, alpha):
  mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name)
  mat.diffuse_color = diffuse
  mat.diffuse_shader = 'LAMBERT'
  mat.diffuse_intensity = 1.0
  mat.specular_color = specular
  mat.specular_shader = 'COOKTORR'
  mat.specular_intensity = 0.2
  mat.alpha = alpha
  mat.ambient = 1
  mat.use_transparency = True
  mat.use_shadows = False
  return mat
```

I wanted to use nodal shading and eevee but I didn't know how to do this.

Expected output (2.79):
[image: blender 2.79 output]

What it's returning now (2.8):
[image: Blender 2.8 output]

Comment: Hello, could you provide a screenshot or image of the effect you expect to achieve ?

Comment: just added thanks for reminding me :) @Gorgious

Comment: read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-gets-greyish-touch

Comment: Thanks so much! @susu