# Grease Pencil: render is darker than what is displayed in the viewport

Tags: lighting, grease-pencil, shadows

2D Animators question:

I have a material with a certain color, but in the rendering it appears a bit darker. See here:

[image: right one is rendered mode]

Maybe there is an light or shadow source.

What I've tryed:

- deleted  all light objects (see layers)

[image: layers]

- unchecked "use lights" in the layers properties (see grease pencil properties)

[image: right one is rendered mode]

- deleted the backround in the world properties

[image: world properties]

Here are also my render settings (opened up light and shadow settings. is anything else needed?) and

[image: render settings]

material settings

[image: material settings]

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and upload images that show your 
current setup and illustrate the problem. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?] 
(https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Done :) Hope this is more clear now?

Comment: my goodness! THANK YOU :D

Comment: world properties - viewport display, set it to white, it doesn't make sense, but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switching the color management to standard.

As far as I know the grease pencil is hopelessly coded in sRGB, so it will look dark if the color transform is set to filmic.

Comment: Related: [blender output is greyish and not white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-is-greyish-and-not-white/176760#176760)

Answer (score 3):

The Grease Pencil Object is reacting to World lighting which is making it darker than normal.

World Lighting can be swithed off by disabling 'Scene World'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to *World Properties > Viewport Display*, set it to white.

I don't know the technical side, but it seems like 2D render in display mode/space

[image: gray viewport display]

[image: white viewport display]