# Mismatching colors from multiple textures (2.90)

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, image, texture-painting

I feel like I'm missing something simple (newbie here), but in **Blender 2.90**, when assigning **multiple image textures** with **MixRGB** nodes, the colors that are shown on the 3D Viewport don't match the colors from each source image.

I believe I need to be in **Material Preview** to show multiple textures.

https://pasteall.org/media/a/2/a2992ddf1e76e271d1fa8ffef3aa052c.blend

There're four **.png** images:

- Base color
- Highlights (white color on transparent background)
- Shadows (grey color on transparent background)
- Final image (combined in Krita as reference)

[image]

I hope I was clear and thank you for reading it.

Comment: Under render properties> all the way down: color management> view transform, set it to normal. Filmic is i think to get a wider dynamic range, but if you want the image to show the same as the original you will have to chnage the viewtransform to normal

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The node setup for this is not quite right for what you want, but upon correcting it as best I could both the reference and the mix looked faded (though they were thankfully the same, so it is possible to emulate Krita's math). This may have to do with the computer I used, though. Do the reference image and the mix image look the same on the plane to you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender image output is greyish and not white](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-is-greyish-and-not-white)

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The idea is to use the image textures as if they're layers like in Krita/Photoshop. I changed the View Transform to Standard but the output still looks washed-out in the viewport for the mix, but the final looks right. I'll look through the links posted more closely.