# White Image appearing grey when saved as RGBA

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a bit of a problem with my blender project.

I need to render this as a transparent animation, so I'm using RGBA on PNGs

The issue is that, whenever I save the white image as RGBA, it appears slightly gray.

Below are the RGBA image and RGB image, from the same render. Why will the color change so much simply by changing the image "save as" format?

[image: RGBA IMAGE]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/176754/blender-image-output-is-greyish-and-not-white/176760#176760

Comment: Thanks for your response Susu, but I've already set the color management to standard and it's still not white for RGBA. When I save the render image as RGB and take it into photoshop, I get pure white, but when I save as RGBA (on the same render result window), I get gray.

Comment: Maybe related. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Comment: Hi Susu, I was able to solve this by adjusting the exposure in the color management section.

Comment: This really helped me! thanks man! i was generating sone alpha maps with the benchmark engine and blender just kept outputting a grey "white" i had to bump it up to 5 but finally got 0,0,0 white on my images, Thanks you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

So after much trial an error, I was able to fix this by changing the exposure value from 0 to 1 in the color management tab.

This was the only way I could get my RGBA image to appear pure white, like the RGB image was.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with getting a white background in Blender 4.1. I tried making the material whiter than 1.0. Tried upping the lights, the exposure, the gamma. It just looked worse and still gray. I fixed it when I reverted everything, **switched the display device from sRGB to P3** (I'm using the image in Google Slides on a MacBook Air) and **changed the AgX "look" in Color Management to "Very High Contrast"**. It looks perfect now!